# Fedora 21 - Gem: change EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY

Tags: fedora, ruby

I am using some locally installed gems in my environment and I would like to change the `EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY` path to `~/.gem/bin`

How could I achieve this?

```
$gem env

  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.2.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.1.5 (2014-11-13 patchlevel 273) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/flyer/.gem/ruby
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/flyer/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/flyer/.gem/specs
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/flyer/.gem/ruby
     - /usr/share/gems
     - /usr/local/share/gems
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /bin
     - /sbin
     - /home/flyer/.local/bin
     - /home/flyer/bin
     - /home/flyer/.local/bin
     - /home/flyer/bin
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your intention was to **install gems' executables into `~/.gem/bin`**, you can set in `~/.gemrc`:

```
gem:
 --bindir ~/.gem/bin 
 # any other gem settings like: 
 --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

It will NOT change `EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY`, but gems' executables will be installed into `~/.gem/bin`. You can check it is set by:

```
$ gem env
- GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - "gem" => "--bindir ~/.gem/bin --no-ri --no-rdoc"
```

To be able to invoke them, add that directory at the beginning of your `PATH`.

Answer (score 3):

You can try

`$ export GEM_HOME = ~/.gem`

This will change your gem executable directory into `~/.gem/bin`

You can confirm that by run `$ gem env` again

If that works you can make it permanent by adding `export GEM_HOME=$HOME/.gem` at the end of file .bashrc or .zshrc

Hope that help!

Answer (score 1):

Here is lines for `.bashrc / .zshrc`:

```bsh
#Ruby + GEM
export GEM_HOME=$HOME/.gem
export PATH=$GEM_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

After this all my gems start works.